when i install flutter app in my emulator its run perfectly but after i stop the app and run again it doesn't run properly
When i install flutter app in my emulator its run perfectly but after i stop the app and run again it doesn't run properly.
First Time Run the App (install first time)
After stop and run show nothing
I want that it will run properly. I try different device but still not work

Yeah it's because during debugging it doesn't save your app state properly. Try running in release mode or build apk and install.
for release :
flutter run -d devicename --release

for build :
flutter build apk --release or --debug


This issue occurs because your debug app retains the state from previous builds. To resolve this, try running your app in release mode.
